# didExitRegion called only once in 15 minutes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I have developed an iOS app using Objective-c that uses location services in the background as well as when app is terminated . I am using `StartUpdatingLocation()`to start the location updates. And in the 
`didUpdateLocations()` I implement the `StartMonitoringForRegion()` 
using the location coordinates I get. Everything works fine.

My question though is that , the `didExitRegion()` 
gets called once in 15 minutes. I am not using iBeacon Regions. I am using Location Regions monitoring. Can anyone explain the behaviour?